# How does indexes work in a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, index

If I have a list of name that are all different and I have to find a specific name,how could indexes help.thi research?How does index work in  a database?I have read other discussion but I haven't understood...

Comment: Well, give us the URL of what you've read (or if it's a book, type it in) and tell us what bits you haven't understood. Unfortunately, as your question stands, it's off-topic as being too broad as @AliRazeghi says. Take the tour, visit the help centre and check out the "Help us to help you" blog. These sites are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them if you follow the guidelines. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Does a filing cabinet by alphabet help find a document?

Answer (score 1):

This is a too broad of a question sadly as each DB Engine might do it differently.

To put it very simply most of them work by making a copy of the data you want sorted in a different way.  This way when you look for a range of data it's already sorted so the DB Engine can very quickly find what you want without scanning everything.

Imagine if you had 800 million records of people, and wanted the last names of everyone who starts with an R but your table is sorted by social security.  It would have to read the entire table to ensure it got every single person who has a last name that starts with R.

You could make a copy of the table to include the data you want (maybe you don't want all the data, just a few fields) and you can sort it by last_name.  Now the DB engine knows where the last names that begin with R are stored.  It goes straight to that area, reads all the "R" records, and then stops once it hits "S".  There is no need to read more thus you save space in memory and execution time.

To get a technical walkthrough and explanation check out this excellent SQL Internals video on Indexing.  Other DB solutions might do it different but many such as MongoDB and SQL Server use a reverse B-Tree to store the index.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn912438?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#mcm-readiness

**Edit: To address the question posted by OP.**

The index can be sorted in *any* way what so ever.  It could be sorted by ID number, a column called 'colour', hexID, alphabetical, really almost whatever you could put in the database engine.  What matters is how you *retrieve or query* the data.  If you query data based on last name then yes, it's not bad.  If you query data based on social security number, then sorting the data alphabetical will not be helpful.

The idea is to avoid scanning the entire table of data to get all the results.  Write your index so that it can retrieve the data quickly. Pretend it was a phone book of everyone in the USA and you want the record for everyone with the name Albert Gonzales, and you have another query that wants the social security number of everyone named Albert Gonzales.  Let's say the phone book is sorted by last name then first name.

Finding Albert Gonzales would be easy in this case.  You open the book to the GONZ section, find Gonzales, then find Albert and you pull out those records.  Instead of reading through 400 million records you read through maybe 5,000.  What if your index key was ONLY sorted by last name though?  Then you'd have to read ALL the Gonzales last names to ensure you got all the ones named Albert.  So your record set to review just went up to 50,000 because you are only sorting by last name.

Now look at getting the first name and last name of whoever has social security number 555-12-111 `(select first_name, last_name from people where social_security IN ('555-12-111'))`.  How many records would you have to read before you find it?  It could be the anywhere from the very last entry or the very first one, thus you'd have to scan everything until you find it since SS# is unique.  Let's say it is in the 200th million record. You just had to scan 200 million records to find it.  If you create a index by social security number though that has the first name and last name in it the index will be sorted by social security number to begin with.  Thus you'd open up the book to the section that starts with 555, then find 12, and then finding 111 is trivial.  You'd save yourself TONS of time.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Ok,so the idea to sort names in alphabetical way is not so bad?I had thought the same thing but I have read in internet that it was a bad idea...

Comment: @Tovelo could you link to *where* did you read it?

Comment: updated my answer to address your question.  Check out the video link I sent you as well. It's very helpful. Also @jkavalik has a good point, show us where you read that.

Comment: Ok,give me some minutes to fid that discussion  and I'll post it:):)Thank you for your help:):)

Comment: I hae an other question,you have written that to find Gonzalez I have to do an index to find gonz.But if I have to find Gigione that index can't be used...or not?

Comment: Then I have read that in a  table only 16 indexes can be added,in case of alphabetical sort the letters are more...I haven't understood very well:)

Comment: @Tovelo when you add an index on one column, that index covers the whole column, values from all rows (in MySQL anyway, some databases allow some filtering, but that is an additional feature, not default).

Comment: Ok but alphabetical letters are 26,how can I add 26 indexes to say to database where to go to find all letters quickly?

Comment: @Tovelo you don't! You do not store 26 letters in 26 columns, you store the names in one column, so one index is enough. Somethink like [this](http://mattfleming.com/files/images/example.gif) (thats internal structure showing how the index might be organized).

Comment: So with one index I can say to database where to find the start of all letters?

Comment: Excuse me,I am confused about this argument:(

Comment: @Tovelo it would be nice if you could find that link to the argument as I have no idea where you got this misconception and about what start of letters you are actually talking :)

Comment: @Tovelo that is correct.  An index in this scenario includes ALL the records but it is SORTED differently.  Just think about it if you were to look up books at the library.  You have the ISBN number.  The catalogue is organized by book name and not ISBN number.  An index on ISBN would be a *COPY* of the same data but ORGANIZED or SORTED by ISBN instead of name.  This way you can very quickly go to the ISBN number and find all the info you want from the book, since it's a copy that is sorted differently.  Does that make sense?  You should really watch the video too.